# Define kineticjs rect background from spritesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kineticjs

Given I have a 40x40px kineticjs rect, and I also have, for example, a 200x200 spritesheet containing 25 40x40 sprites and I want to give the kineticjs rect a background of one of the individual sprites.. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can define a custom `Kinetic.Shape` to display your clipped sprite.**

The `Kinetic.Shape`'s gives you a wrapped canvas context upon which to draw as if you were drawing on a native canvas. The wrapped canvas context has most, but not all, of the functionality of a native canvas context.

You can use the clipping version of `context.drawImage` to clip a sprite from your spritesheet image object and draw it onto the custom shape.

Then use `context.rect` to draw a stroked border around your Kinetic.Shape containing the clipped sprite.

**Here is example code and a Demo:**

```js
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    // ??? Fix very wierd glitch!
    // The Kinetic.Shape is not cleared if it's the only element on the canvas
    layer.add(new Kinetic.Circle({x:-300,y:250,radius:25,fill:'red'}));
    layer.draw();

var spriteRect;
var sw=471/5;
var sh=255/2;

var spritesheet=new Image();
spritesheet.crossOrigin='anonymous';
spritesheet.onload=start;
spritesheet.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/avatars.png";
function start(){

    spriteRect = new Kinetic.Shape({
        x: 20,
        y: 30,
        stroke:'black',
        strokeWidth:3,
        draggable:true,
        drawFunc: function(ctx) {
          // clip a sprite from the spritesheet and draw it on spriteRect
          ctx.drawImage(spritesheet, sw*1,0,sw,sh, 0,0,sw,sh);
          // draw a stroked border around the image
          ctx.rect(0,0,sw,sh);
          // tell KineticJS to draw the image + border on the layer
          ctx.fillStrokeShape(this);
        }
    });
    layer.add(spriteRect);
    layer.draw();   


}
```

```css
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kineticjs/5.2.0/kinetic.min.js"></script>
<h4>A draggable sprite-rect.</h4>
<div id="container"></div>
<h4>The spritesheet image</h4>
<img cross-origin=anonymous src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/avatars.png'>
```

BTW, KineticJS has been retired, but Stackoverflow member @lavrton has forked KineticJS in the form of KonvaJS: http://konvajs.github.io/. I can enthusiastically recommend KonvaJS!

Comment: Thanks mark, especially for the link to the fork! I get an error when using your code: 

'Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'

Beforehand I define the image:

var test_image = new Kinetic.Image();
test_image.src = 'sprites.png';

I can't quite see why it isn't working... any ideas?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wTzDNANz is the function where I use the code... by adding the test_image.onload the above error doesn't appear but neither does the picture in the canvas.

Comment: You must supply a fully loaded image object (your spritesheet image). So fix the error message by replacing `spritesheet` with your valid spritesheet image.

Comment: I managed to get it to correctly crop and display the image (http://pastebin.com/bJWYhQK7) however now it seems that despite setting draggable as true, the shape cannot be dragged? I checked the documentation and draggable is a property for Kinetic Shape... so I'm at a loss to why this is happening? Thanks for all your help so far... I've been stuck on this for hours :P

Comment: I should also mention I removed ctx.strokeRect(0,0,40,40); as it threw up an error in the console saying it wasn't a function.

Comment: Yep, `strokeRect` should be `rect` (how quickly we forget...!). I've added a working demo snippet to my answer. As I was doing the demo, I came across a glitch I've not seen before in KineticJS. If the only object on the layer is a draggable `Kinetic.Shape` then that shape is incorrectly not erased as it's being dragged. I compensated by adding a useless, off-stage Kinetic.Circle so the Kinetic.Shape wouldn't be lonely(?!). Anyway, good luck with your project!

Comment: Hey! Your demo was wonderful, especially pointing out/discovering that weird bug! I have it working how I want now! Really appreciate your persistence =D Thanks again!